# ¿como rellenar la tabla en wxpython con sqlite3 y pyhton3?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3, wxpython

Estoy haciendo una consulta a una BD y la guardo en una variable (me la convierte en una tupla) estoy tratando de rellenar una grilla a través de un ciclo. El ciclo no me deja iterar la variable con la consulta. Así que la igualo a un diccionario a intentar a través de un ciclo también. Sucede que me lo guarda todo en una sola llave (porque todo esta junto) como hago yo para que cuando pare un registro (o sea que el siguiente valor sea el id) me cree otra llave con la info y así sucesivamente. Pensaba en alguna clase de info pero no puedo evaluarla como ID o y no creo poder posición ya que la tupla no me agarra posiciones

primer intento:

```
Self.dicc={}
Self.info=(tablas["modulo"])
For row in self.info:
Self.dicc[row]=self.info
For row in self.dicc:
  For col in range (tablas["columnas"]):
   Self.tabla.setcellvalue(row,col,self.dicc[row])
```

Comment: setcellvalue da el siguiente error: Typeerror:grid.setcellvalue():arguments did not match any overloaded call Eso quiere decir que le paso parámetros que no son Pero me dice que el argumento uno no debe recibir un int pero es la posición en fila donde lo recibe así que si debe recibirlo. Y me dice el tercero que no debe ser tupla. Por ende. Debo guardar no solo registro separado de registro en el diccionario. Si no también dato separado de dat

Comment: lo que acabas de comentar considera agregarlo a tu pregunta